# How do I solve an LTI difference equation where a Kronecker delta or a unit step is the input?

Tags: recurrence-relations

In my mind, the steps are

- 1: Find the homogeneous solution using the characteristic equation
- 2: Use "undetermined coefficients" method of finding the particular solution.

However, what is the form of the particular solution for these kinds of equations?

I am trying to find the general form of $x[n]$:
$$
x[n] + x[n-1] = {\delta}[n]
$$

Is there no way to solve this using the Z-transform?

Comment: We find that $x[n] = (-1)^n \cdot u[n]$ (where $u[n]$ denotes the unit step function) is a particular solution.  It is not clear what the correct "guess" corresponding to $\delta[n]$ should have been.

Comment: In general, using $\delta[n]$ as our forcing function and imposing the condition $x[n] = 0$ for $n < 0$ leads to the unit impulse response of the difference operator.  Because the unit impulse of operators is so diverse, I'm inclined to think that there is no good Ansatz for the response (i.e. no way to set up the method of undetermined coefficients).

Comment: Note that solving this system with $x[n] = 0$ for $n<0$ is equivalent to solving the homogeneous problem $x[n] + x[n-1] = \delta[n]$ with the initial condition $x[0] = \delta[0] = 1$.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like that, 1.) $x[n]=(-1)^n$ is a homogeneous solution to your example problem, to 2.) find via *variation of coefficients*
$$
x[n]=(-1)\cdot y[n]\implies y[n]-y[n-1]=\delta[n],
$$
using that the delta sequence is zero almost everywhere, so that the alternating sign change does not influence it.

Now if you set $y[n]=0$ for $n<0$, then if follows that $y[n]=1$ for $n\ge 0$, as the recursion tells you that it is the previous value except at $n=0$, where $1$ is added.

---

The *method of undetermined coefficients* is not applicable here, as it requires that the right side is composed of terms $r[n]=p(n)q^n$ for some $q\ne0$ and some polynomial $p(n)$.

Comment: What do you mean by "that"?

Comment: The variation of coefficients, as $x[n]=(-1)^n$ is a homogeneous solution to your problem.

Comment: but the question is about the unrelated [method of undetermined coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_undetermined_coefficients).

Comment: That is not applicable here, as the right side is not of the form $p(n)q^n$ for a polynomial $p(n)$.

Comment: Then that is what you should say in your answer.  As your post is written, it does not address the question actually being asked.